# ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Invalid argument Phpexcel Laravel

Tags: phpexcel, laravel-5.4, php-ziparchive

I am working on append excel content into existing excel file and save it in a predefined directory with different name. I am using the Laravel 5.4 framework for my application.

I am using the below code to create excel file and save it on specified location:

```
$objPHPExcel = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');  

//Load Existing excel file into I want to append  
$objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load(getDocumentPath().'/Report_Template_UG.xlsx');  

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  

//Here I have Written code to insert my data into loaded excel file  

$today = date('d-m-Y');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$filename = 'Report_'.$today.' '.$time.'.xlsx';  

//welcomed is the root directory name of laravel project
$dir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\welcomed\storage\documents\';  
$filepath = $dir . $filename;  
$objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  
$objWriter->save($path);
```

On executing the above code, I am gettign the below error:

```
ErrorException in Excel2007.php line 377:  
ZipArchive::close(): Renaming temporary file failed: Invalid argument
```

Can anyone please tell me, What I have done wrong in above code or do I have missed something?

Thanks